# Should you use a construct with invoke - or just use invoke?

Tags: php, laravel

On my resource controllers I have the usual methods, `index` `store` `update` etc.

I also have a `construct` that manages middleware and authorization like so:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:sanctum')->only(['index', 'update', 'destroy']);
        $this->authorizeResource(User::class, 'user');
    }
```

On other occasions, such as in single method controllers I just use `invoke`:

```
public function __invoke()
    {
        return new UserResource(auth()->user());
    }
```

If I wanted to add middleware and an authroization policy, should I add it to the `invoke` method or use a seperate `construct` method as per my resource contoller detailed above?

Comment: Even with single method controllers you can have a constructor

Answer (score 5):

A constructor method is executed when a new object instance is created, i.e. when `new Something()` is being called. In contrast, the `__invoke()` magic method is called only when the code is trying to call an object as a function (see [callbacks / the callable type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)).

```
<?php

class CanCallMe
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    echo "Constructor executed.";
  }
  public function __invoke()
  {
    echo "Invoked.";
  }
}

function call(callable $callback)
{
  callback();
}

$callback = new CanCallMe(); // Constructor is executed here.
call($callback); // This is when the __invoke() method will be executed.
```

**Edit:** In the context of Laravel  / single action controllers: Middleware (including those defined by the controller) are gathered *before* the route is run (i.e. `__invoke` is called). This means middleware added within the `__invoke` method will *not* be run. The proof of the pudding is in the eating... Try it out.

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer the question.

Comment: @panthro I edited my response to make it more explicit for your Laravel use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use __construct and __invoke methods simultaneously. I think you can use __construct method for that purpose.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).